# Codeception: Call to undefined method FunctionalTester::expectException

Tags: codeception

According to the Codeption [documentation](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Asserts#expectException) I should be able to catch an `HttpException` by running the following:

```
$I->expectException(HttpException::class, function () {
    $I->amOnRoute('that-doesnt/exist');
});
```

However instead I get en error:

> [RuntimeException] Call to undefined method
>   FunctionalTester::expectException

I am using `Codeception 2.4.3`

Comment: Have you enabled Asserts module in functional.suite.yml?

Comment: and I do not... well thats embarrassing. Please put as answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to make `expectException` method available in the tests, Assert module must be enabled in functional.suite.yml file:

```
modules:
    enabled:
        - Asserts
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Naktibalda answer - in latest version of Codeception `expectException` was deprecated and replaced with `expectThrowable`:
https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Asserts#expectThrowable